# Why alphas=alphas in RidgeCV in this example?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I need to implement Lasso and Ridge Regression and calculate hyperparameters by means of cross-validation.
I found the code that does it, but I cannot quite understand it.

```
lassocv = LassoCV(alphas=None, cv=15, max_iter=100000, normalize=True)
lassocv.fit(X_train, y_train)
lasso = Lasso(alpha=lassocv.alpha_, normalize=True)
lasso.fit(X_train, y_train)
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_val, lasso.predict(X_val)))

ridgecv = RidgeCV(alphas=alphas, normalize=True)
ridgecv.fit(X_train, y_train)
ridge = Ridge(alpha=ridgecv.alpha_, normalize=True)
ridge.fit(X_train, y_train)
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_val, ridge.predict(X_val)))
```

So, why alphas=alphas in RidgeCV? If I write alphas=None, an error occurs. Why is it not necessary to write cv for ridgecv?

Comment: Hey @xxx, welcome to StackOverflow! The three questions you are asking here seem independent and are about different models, you should rather ask them separately. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is related to the way the strength of regularization has been set on the different models.

In RidgeCV, you need to declare `alpha`s explicitly because the parameter tuning is not  done on the basis of the error calculated from cross-validation.

In LassoCV however, they have a way of automatically calculating `alpha`s from the CV error. However, if you want to set them explicitly, you can do so by changing the optional parameters: `n_alpha` and `alphas`

Refer: https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf
Chapter 7 section 4 for further details.